Deleting elements of a navigation property on update of the parent entity
I have the following payload sent to my API, which creates records into the database
{
    "id": null,
    "child": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "parentId": null
            "quantity": 1,
            "rate": 5.5
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "parentId": null,
            "quantity": 15,
            "rate": 75.5
        }
    ]
}

This correctly creates the parent entity and the child entities with the appropriate foreign keys, as configured in my model.
Now, if I send this payload to update the child entities, this does work also.
{
    "id": "365A71AD-8625-4701-904B-E21DCF62E343",
    "child": [
        {
            "id": "BC889B2F-1BFD-4E3E-9C23-078948A16ED5",
            "parentId": "365A71AD-8625-4701-904B-E21DCF62E343"
            "quantity": 999,
            "rate": 150
        },
        {
            "id": "F56C9F80-0238-4F03-9CA0-D591FCFE3537",
            "parentId": "365A71AD-8625-4701-904B-E21DCF62E343",
            "quantity": 115,
            "rate": 5
        }
    ]
}

The way I've done this, in the update logic:
var incomingNavigationProperties = databaseContext.Entry(incomingDtoCastedToDatabaseType).Navigations;
var existingNavigationProperties = databaseContext.Entry(existingEntityFetchedFromDatabase).Navigations;
foreach(var navObj in incomingNavigationProperties)
{
    foreach(var navExist in existingNavigationProperties)
    {
        if(navObj.Metadata.Name == navExist.Metadata.Name)
        {
            navExist.CurrentValue = navObj.CurrentValue;
        }
    }
}

Works fine for updates, but if I send the same payload to the update logic, but with a missing member in the child navigation property, the child entity isn't deleted from the databse. Is there any way to configure EF so it does so ?
Thanks.

You need to detect and handle inserts and deletes. Inserts are easy as the PK will be null or default. For deletes take the IDs from existing .Except() the Ids from the updated and that will give you which items from the existing set to remove.

You can try to  enable cascade delete in the model configuration, something like modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>() .HasMany(p => p.Children) .WithOne(c => c.Parent) .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);.
